# cobertura report

Tags: report, code-coverage, cobertura

I am making a  jar file of project1 and placing the jar file in project2.
For project2 I'm able to create the coberatura report.

My question is how do I get the  cobertura report for project1(in jar format) which is in project2?

Comment: I got solution.

same follow the procedure.instrumented the class of project1 and build the jar and placed in project2. .ser file created placed in tomcat home path.i deployed project2 in tomcat and run the application. after stopping tomcat the .ser file is overloaded.now generate the report as given in cobertura site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution.

1. instrumented the class of project1
2. build the jar
3. place the jar in project2.
4. `.ser` file created placed in tomcat home path.

I deployed project2 in tomcat and ran the application.

After stopping tomcat the .ser file was overwritten. 
Now generate the report.